# reading and writing at Idris

Tags: idris

I am in my first steps of learing "Idris". 
I am using this tutorial: http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/starting.html

I created file called "hello.idr".
The content of the file is :

```
module Main

main : IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello world"
```

I enterd this line at the shell prompt:"idris hello.idr -o hello"
but something unexcpeted occurred 
[image: print screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
module Main

main : IO () 
main = putStrLn "Hello world"
```

everything works as it should.

```
~$ idris hello.idr -o hello
~$ ./hello
Hello world
```

If it does not, you have a broken idris installation I would assume, and depending on your OS you need to follow different steps to install a binary installation.

For OS X I simply recommend `brew install idris` or have a look at https://www.idris-lang.org/download/